# jquery валидация полей формы при вводе пользователя, нужно что бы повторные запросы отправлялись не чаще раз в секунду

Tags: jquery, валидация, forms

Есть свой плагин валидации полей формы при вводе пользователя. При вводе в любое поле по событию keyup отсылаетcя ajax запрос на сервер. В callback если поле не валидно, показываем ошибку, также скрываем/показываем кнопку submit в зависимости от валидности текущего и других полей.

В результате конечно полно ajax запросов происходит при вводе пользователя. Все это вроде особо не тормозит, но хотелось бы сделать оптимальнее, то есть что бы запросы не отправлялись чаще чем например один раз в секунду.

Как это сделать например при помощи setInterval
Тк там логика специфичная весьма именно для нашего проекта. Показываю только главное.

```
jQuery.fn.nickmsk = function(o){
    //console.log(o);
    this.bind('keyup.nickmsk', function(e) {
        this.is_backspace = false;
        if (e.keyCode == 8) this.is_backspace = true;
        var k = e.charCode || e.keyCode || e.which;

        if (e.ctrlKey || e.altKey || e.metaKey) {
            //Ignore
            return true;
        } 
        else if ((k >= 32 && k <= 125) || k > 186) 
        {
            //typeable characters
            //var c = String.fromCharCode(k);
        }
        else if(e.keyCode != 8)
        {
            return true;
        }

        if(e.keyCode >= 37  && e.keyCode <= 40)
        {
            return  true;
        }

            var fldtext = $(this).val(); //значение поля к котором привязан плагин
           fldtext = fldtext.replace('&', '%26');
           var form = o.form;  //форма которая содержит поле.
            var qs = "&form=" + form + "&checkstr=" + fldtext; 
            $.ajax(
            {
                url: '/ajax/nickname.php',
                data: qs,
                dataType: 'json',
                type: 'post',
                beforeSend: function() { 
                //$("#check_av").show();
                },
                success: function (json) {
                    //Показываем или скрываем ошибку и кнопку отправить. 

                }
            });

        }


    });
};
```

Вызываеться плагин так

```
$("#login").unbind();
$("#login").nickmsk({form: $("#regist_form") });

$("#passwd1").unbind();
$("#passwd1").nickmsk({form: $("#regist_form")  });
```

На самом деле параметров больше. Но это не суть.
Что бы тут вынести в SetTimeout что бы при вводе и при проверке каждого поля была пауза между запросами в 1 сек

Comment: Клиентскую валидацию собственно и делали чтобы не нагружать сервер лишний раз, а вы делаете все наоборот. )))

Comment: Клиентскую авторизацию все равно ведь нужно повторять не сервере в целях безопасности. Вот я и упрощаю задачу, что бы проверять только на сервере, а не делать часть проверок на клиенте, дублировать их на сервере, а часть что требуют обращения к БД на сервере. Не советуете подобное? Даже если проверять только уникальность E-mail обращаясь к серверу то все равно ведь каждый ввод символа пользователем вызывает ajax запрос.  Вот и хотелось бы что бы запросы шли не один за другим,а  с промежутком.

Comment: Думаю что то вроде этого нужно http://benalman.com/code/projects/jquery-throttle-debounce/examples/debounce/ или проще http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1909441/jquery-keyup-delay

Comment: И все равно потом нужно будет повторно все перепроверить на сервере. В чем выигрыш? На клиенте нужно проверять то что можно проверить, уникальность это уже не клиентская проблема.

Comment: Я наверное не очень понятно написал. Вижу два подхода. 1) Проверять заполненность поля, формат мейла на клиенте, проверять уникальность ajax запросом к серверу, затем при отправки формы проверять и заполненность и формат и уникальность на сервере. Насколько я понимаю таким образом обычно и делают. 2) Проверять и заполенность поля и формат и уникальность ajax запросом к серверу и все это перепроверять опять же на сервере при отправке формы. Таким образом сделано у меня. Это субъективно проще и нет времени переделывать как в варианте 1. Но хотелось бы что слишком часто запросы к серверу не шли.